# How do I access variables within a context object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, scope

I have this code:

```
inner class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        val colWidth = width / (colCount + 1) // works out the width of each column
        var colTouch = event.x.toInt() / colWidth // works out what column has been selected

        val rowHeight = height / ((rowCount * 2) + 1)
        var rowTouch = event.y.toInt() / rowHeight

        return true
    }

}
```

As you can see, `n` is used as a reference to the context. Within the context is an object `boxGame`. Here's an example of what I mean.

[image: Screenshot of the debugging tool in Android Studio]

However, I cannot figure out how I can access that object from `n`. I would have thought it would be `n.boxGame` but Android Studio flags that as wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a Context to share information between you app components and that is not how it should be done. If you could tell us what are you trying to accomplish we could suggest a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @JuanMartinez I'm trying to call the game's logic from the GameView class. Granted, they are in separate modules. I need a way for the game to detect when the user has tapped and handle the request.

Comment: Even if they are in separate modules, the module holding your GameView class should be dependent on your game logic's module, because it clearly needs to access the game  logic to listen for those taps. If that's possible, you could define an interface GameEventListener in your game logic's module that your GameView class could implement. Otherwise, you should implement some broadcasting mechanism. Let me know which one is the case and I can guide you through.

Comment: @JuanMartinez I'm able to implement the interface. How would I go about implementing both the new interface and the View class required for my GameView?

Comment: I hope to have understood you issue, I tried to elaborate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass information from your GameView to your Game when the view receives a tap event, you can write a `GameViewEventListener` interface and make your game implement that interface in order to listen for those game view events.

```
interface GameViewEventListener {
  fun onTapEvent(rowHeight: Double, rowTouch: Double)
  // other events
}
```

In your GameView class, you need to allow listeners to subscribe and unsubscribe to these game events. For that, you could simply keep an instance field:

```
private var gameEventListener: GameViewEVentListener? = null
```

Then, when an event occurs, you can notify the listener about it:

```
 override fun onSingleTapUp(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        val colWidth = width / (colCount + 1) // works out the width of each column
        var colTouch = event.x.toInt() / colWidth // works out what column has been selected

        val rowHeight = height / ((rowCount * 2) + 1)
        var rowTouch = event.y.toInt() / rowHeight

        gameEventListener?.onTapEvent(rowHeight, rowTouch)

        return true
    }
```

Finally, you need to implement that interface in your Game class:

```
override fun onTapEvent(rowHeight: Double, rowTouch: Double) {
    // do something
}
```

and don't forget to subscribe/unsubscribe when needed (you can create some instance methods in GameView for that):

```
// whenever you want to start listening for events
gameView.gameEventListener = this

...

// whenever you want to stop listening
gameView.gameEventListener = null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't have a comment privilege. I think you should tell us what `boxGame` is and how it could be in a context. Is it an activity name or a fragment name?

You can only call `n.boxGame` only when `Context` has a public variable called `boxGame`, but there is not such thing AFAIK.